# Declaring a field extending some type

Tags: java, generics

I am having some problems with my syntax. I am looking all over and could not find the correct thing (I actually do not know, what would be the phrase to search). So here is the problem. For simplicity, lets assume I have 4 classes:

class A:

```
public abstract class A{
}
```

class B:

```
public class B extends A{
    //some methods and fields
}
```

class C:

```
public class C extends A{
    //some other methods
}
```

class D:

```
public class D{
    protected ? value;
}
```

Here I have a problem, because I do not know what to put instead of `?` in `class D`, if I want to define `?` as some sub-class of `A`. I know an option is just to write `A` instead of `?`, but I think that this could be more specified, for example something like `<T extends A>`.

Is this even possible?

-edit-

From answers below, I saw that approach would be, to use raw types. But nevertheless, can anyone confirm that a construct like this, does not exist in java? That you could create a field of generic type `T` (extending some class), but the class containing this field does not have a generic parameter `T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generic class as follows:

```
public class D<T extends A> {
    protected T value;
}
```

`MyClass` isn't dependent of `T` as you pretend in your comment above. You can instantiate an instance without precising wildcard. Therefore, `T` would still be remplaced by `A` at compile-time 
This concept is called: **Raw types**

For more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Comment: Yes, this could be a way to approach, But it produces some compile errors... I think I will go with these Raw Types.

Comment: Sorry, not errors, I meant warnings. References to generic type should be parameterized.

Comment: To avoid raw types, prefer at least declaring your instance with the less specific allowed types => `A` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should specific to this value Type at run time .

```
public class D<T extends A>{
    protected T value;
}

D<B> d =new D<B>();
D<A> d1 = new D<A>();
```

Answer (score 1):

**-** Use `Type Parameter`,

**Eg:**

```
public class MyClass<T extends A>{

   T value;

}
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of this possibility. But here `MyClass` is dependent of the value of `T`. Is it possible to do this without outer class being dependent of `T`?

Comment: @Nejc, OuterClass....?? are you using Inner class....?? `If yes then Outer class can extends to something and its Inner class or classes can extend to something else....`

Comment: By outer class I meant `D`.